# Make: Static recipes for dynamic subdirectories

Tags: gnu-make

Given a hierarchy of the (simplified) form

```
A
  source
  target
B  
  source
  target
...
```

where there is specifically one `target` in each subdirectory which is to be built from the one `source` therein. I'd like to achieve this by make.

Of course, a makefile such as

```
%target: %source
    ...
```

would do the job, but this could also match `A/wrong_target`. Removing the `%`'s however does not work; it seems that `target` then only matches in `.` but in no subdirectory.

Any good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "a hierarchy" do you mean a directory hierarchy?

Why don't you just enforce the directory by including the "/", like this:

```
%/target: %/source
         ....
```

Comment: I am sorry for not having had the idea to try this one; thank you.